# Why half of my dispatch functions are not working?

Tags: reactjs, redux

My middle function (enemyLoseHp) works perfectly as intended. However, when it calls another functions everything that's inside `return function(dispatch)` is not working.

Here is the broken example:

```
const getEnemyHp = (i) => {
    console.log('reached');
    return function (getState){
        console.log('not reached');
        return getState().enemy[i].stats.hp;
    }
}



export const enemyLoseHp = (hp, i) => {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'ENEMY_LOSE_HP',
            hp,
            i
        })
        let remainingHp = getEnemyHp(i);
        if (remainingHp <= 0) {
            killEnemy(i);
        }
    }
}

export const killEnemy = (i) => {
    console.log('reached')
    return function (dispatch) {
        console.log('not reached')
        dispatch({
            type: 'KILL_ENEMY',
            i
        })
    } 
}
```

I dont have these issues if I pass getState manually to them like the code below, but I dont think thats how I should make it:

```
const getEnemyHp = (i, getState) => {
    console.log(getState().enemy[i].stats.hp)
    return getState().enemy[i].stats.hp;
}



export const enemyLoseHp = (hp, i) => {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'ENEMY_LOSE_HP',
            hp,
            i
        })
        let remainingHp = getEnemyHp(i, getState);
        if (remainingHp <= 0) {
            killEnemy(i, dispatch);
        }
    }
}

export const killEnemy = (i, dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'KILL_ENEMY',
            i
        })
}
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `getEnemyHp` returns a function which you never call. You could do this:

```
export const enemyLoseHp = (hp, i) => {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({
        type: 'ENEMY_LOSE_HP',
        hp,
        i
    })
    let remainingHp = getEnemyHp(i)(getState);
    if (remainingHp <= 0) {
      killEnemy(i);
    }
  }
}
```

While this technically works, you may be able to solve this more cleanly by connecting your component to the store in a way that avoids the use of `getState` altogether. (Though I can't say for sure without seeing more of your code.)

Comment: I dont quite understand whats going on. If I dont call the function within `getEnemyHp` then technically I also dont call one in `enemyLoseHp'. There is no more code for now, as these are all my actions now. Technically I could avoid using getState, however I would need to transfer those functions to react component and would need to create mess and probably some async functions. At this point id rather just pass getState to those functions, but I still cant grasp why it doesnt work.

Comment: How are you calling `enemyLoseHp`? Is it being dispatched?

Comment: Oh, I meant `killEnemy` sorry. It should in theory dispatch, but it doesnt

Comment: `enemyLoseHp` and `killEnemy` look like asyncActionCreators. Are you using redux-thunk? If so, and you dispatch those asyncActionCreators then the returned functions are automatically called when the async activity resolves. In your case there doesn't appear to be any async operations, so the returned functions should execute immediately so long as you use `dispatch` instead of calling the functions directly.